# Linux subnets isolation

Tags: linux, routing, bridge

I have following configuration on my system

```
                   | br0 (lan0 to lanX + WiFi Home SSID) 
ethX(internet) -     
                   | br1 (WiFi Guest SSID).
```

I need to have both bridges access the internet (nat'ed via ethX) but isolated one each other.

I would expect that by default routing between bridge interfaces will not be enabled, but it doesn't seem to be a case and I can ping from my guest network to home network.

I think I can use iptable to block traffic from br0 to br1, but I hope to find a more elegant solution that will allow routing only to an upstream interface without the need to configure special rules for each subnet I add to the system.

Is any available? I will be ok using iptables as well but hope that I can setup a positive rule i.e., routing toward ethX allowed rest is blocked.

Thanks, 
Ilya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to drop everything first, then allow forwarding on the interface combination(s) you want, eg:

```
iptables -F FORWARD
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o br1 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

.. and so on.  The setup above allows your trusted network `br0` to reach the untrusted `br1`, but not the other way around.  Any more interfaces you add to the system won't be able to forward unless you specifically add them to the list above.  If you want `br0` to be able to forward everywhere, do it like this:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

All networks should still be able to go out your NAT interface `ethX`.